# How to handle Exponential values in shell script

Tags: unix, awk

I have a shell script that connects to a database and returns a value like this `105465694502.823933272271`.

But my script returning it as `1.505E+12`. I need to print the value as I shown above.

Could someone please help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show as some code.

Answer (score 0):

Use **printf**

For awk
   `printf "%12.12f", FOO;`
will give you control over how the numbers are displayed.

In bash, it is the same thing except you don't need a comma between the format string and the variable being printed

`printf "%12.12f" ${foo}`